# Proving that $T_e(U(n))\subset \mathfrak{u}(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to prove that $T_e(U(n))\subset \mathfrak{u}(n)$ and for this I am taking $X\in T_e(U(n))$ and I need to prove that $X+X^*=0$. As $X\in T_e(U(n))$ then $X=\dot\gamma(0)$ for some $\gamma:I\to U(n)$, then $$X+X^*=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\gamma(t)+(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\gamma(t))^*=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(\gamma(t)+\gamma(t)^*)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} 0=0$$

but I am not sure if $(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\gamma(t))^*=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\gamma(t)^*$, could someone help me to say if what I do is correct or if there is any other way that is correct? Thank you!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447372/showing-that-lieun-mathfrakun) (same question).

Comment: Why are you looking at $\gamma(t)+\gamma(t)^*$? What is the definition of $U(n)$? (Yes, if you write down the limit definition of the derivative, you'll see that the Hermitian conjugate of the derivative is the derivative of the Hermitian conjugate.)